# Why can't I generate a Javadoc in Eclipse (UTF error)?

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, javadoc

Going to Project --> Generate Javadoc, click Finish and the following error message appears: "Could not launch Javadoc command. See log for details. Reason: UTF"

Firstly, the log is empty and secondly I have changed the UTF encoding to the standard UTF-8 numerous times and it makes no difference.

Upon clicking the "details" button, it reveals a box that again just says "UTF".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take a look for the enconding of the workspace and also for the encoding of the project itself, sometimes it's different.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have checked both and they are both UTF-8.

Comment: that sounds very strange. Are you using any special characters? Because maybe one "solution" is to remove those characters and try to execute again the Javadoc generation. If that doesn't work, maybe something is wrong with your IDE.

Comment: I don't think I'm using any special characters, I may have to reinstall my IDE. Which would be a massive pain. Thanks for the help!